# AWS EventBridge API Destination can't connect to EC2 private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My goal is to forward messages from EventBridge over HTTPS to an instance in EC2 running httpd server. The instance only has its private IP.

It turned out that the EventBridge's API Destination with its Targets and Connections works beautifully with external IPs, but no communication is happening to the Private IP. As part of the experiment Security is set to accept all https/http connections from all 0.0.0.0/0.

I am seriously considering EventBridge -> Lambda function with VPC bind -> EC2 Private IP.

But I am having that nagging feel that I maybe missing something with the API Destination, some network magic? An endpoint?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EventBridge over HTTPS to an instance in EC2 running httpd server. The instance only has its private IP.

You can't do this. HTTPS requires **valid public domain** with **valid public SSL** certificate. This in turn requires your instance to be accessible from the internet.

The instance itself can be private only, but in that case you have to front it with internet facing **ALB**, which will handle HTTPS for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like a good reason to master Lambda Functions.

Too bad AWS API Destination does not support VPC integration with DNS and private routing, it would have been handy.

Disabling name check for a cert for development purposes would have been nice.

Comment: Is there any sensible and secure way to restrict an endpoint to accept requests only from event bridge api destinations if that endpoint is an api gateway endpoint in the same aws account using resource policies or otherwise