# API Destination [AWS - Event Bridge] could not be created for HTTPS endpoint which is within the VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduling, aws-event-bridge

I have a **PUT API** that can be accessed within the VPN. I have to invoke that API with a scheduler function. I found Event Bridge is a useful serverless resource that we can use to trigger the endpoint.

I created a connection and when I create the API Destination, The AWS Console shows the following error.

```
Failed to create the API Destinations. ParameterInvocationEndpoint is not valid. Reason: Endpoint 'https://test.net/events/test' is invalid. please provide a valid HTTPS endpoint URL
```

My PUT API is working, I confirmed with the postman.

Can anyone assist me to identify the issue to create the API Destination?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS EventBridge API Destination can't connect to EC2 private IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728045/aws-eventbridge-api-destination-cant-connect-to-ec2-private-ip)

Comment: Something that happened to me: I was creating an API destination to a public endpoint, but, whatever served that endpoint, was also in the deploy. I think AWS makes a ping or something to the api destination, and if it can't reach it, for whatever reason, -outages happen in the best families - it will give this error

Answer (score 3):

EventBridge doesn't run inside your VPC. It doesn't have access to your private VPC resources. The solution is to have EventBridge trigger the invocation of an AWS Lambda function that is configured to run inside your VPC, and then make your API call via the Lambda function.

Comment: Another thing, Is it possible to give  VPC private resources access to event bridge?

Comment: What specifically are you asking me to provide AWS documentation for?

Comment: What does "Don't be serious" mean? You are asking a vague question about documentation. Are you asking me to show you documentation that EventBridge doesn't run in a VPC? What are you asking for specifically?